# Apache won't start with ColdFusion 10: mod_jk.conf procedure not found

Tags: apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, mod-jk

I'm trying to install ColdFusion 10 on Apache 2.4.4 with Windows 7. I set up Apache et al with WAMP Server (I needed PHP as well), made sure everything was working great there, and then ran the ColdFusion installation after. ColdFusion installation seemed to complete successfully, but Apache was not able to restart with ColdFusion enabled.

Windows Event Viewer reports the following error with Apache Service:

- `httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 548 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/conf/mod_jk.conf: Cannot load c:/ColdFusion10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so into server: The specified procedure could not be found.`

That's referencing this line from mod_jk.conf:

`LoadModule    jk_module  "c:/ColdFusion10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so"`

I copied+pasted, and there doesn't seem to be a problem with that path. mod_jk.so is there.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What account is the Apache service running under? You may need to grant permissions to that account to the wsconfig folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Officially CF 10](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf10/coldfusion10-support-matrix.pdf) requires Apache 2.2.xx. It won't work with Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

It will still fire the same error with Apache 2.2 in XAMP - and Apache won't start. If you comment out the call to the module in your httpd.conf - Apache will start.

I have the same issue. I have tried CF 9 and CF 10 with various Apache builds on Windows 7 with the same problem.

Update - I found this page http://forums.adobe.com/thread/764843 - similar issue, I downloaded the 32bit version and re ran a clean install and everything works as expected.

Scott