# Installing ColdFusion 9 on Ubuntu 14.04, getting error running connector wizard

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, coldfusion, jrun

#### The Setup:

I'm trying to install ColdFusion 9 on Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4.7. Seriously. Don't ask.

- Spun up a Vagrant Box ([xplore/ubuntu-14.04](https://vagrantcloud.com/xplore/ubuntu-14.04)) that has the LAMP stack installed;
- Performed `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`;
- Installed `libstdc++5` (but still got a warning that CF couldn't verify it was installed);
- Installed CF from `ColdFusion_9_WWEJ_linux64.bin`.

I had to create a symlink to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` called `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` in order to get CF installed, because CF9 doesn't allow you to specify an apache config filename, but other than that everything went smoothly.

#### The Problem:

When I start CF using `./opt/coldfusion9/bin/coldfusion start` I get this message:

```
There was an error while running the connector wizard
Connector installation was not successful
```

...which is the result of `cf-connectors.sh` modifying my `apache2.conf`, telling it to load the module `/opt/coldfusion9/runtime/lib/wsconfig/1/mod_jrun22.so`, then attempting to restart Apache and failing due to this error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 223 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Cannot load /opt/coldfusion9/runtime/lib/wsconfig/1/mod_jrun22.so into server:
/opt/coldfusion9/runtime/lib/wsconfig/1/mod_jrun22.so:
undefined symbol: ap_log_error
```

#### Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

I tailed the Apache error log, but that wasn't much help:

```
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1516] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1516] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 1516] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

The JRun binary file does exist, in `/opt/coldfusion9/runtime/bin/jrun`. However, I've seen [tutorials like this one](http://www.aaronwest.net/blog/index.cfm/2011/1/24/Super-Guide-Installing-ColdFusion-9-on-Ubuntu-Linux) that show it being located in `/opt/jrun4`...which is weird because my version of CF9 is referencing `mod_jrun22.so`, leading me to believe there is a version difference.

Running `./opt/coldfusion9/runtime/bin/jrun status`, I get this output:

```
The coldfusion server is running
No jndi.properties file was found in samples's SERVER-INF directory. The JRun kernel requires JNDI information.
The samples server is not running
The admin server is not running
```

...which tells me that there is a missing `indi.properties` file, and that the samples and admin servers are not running. I assume that is a result of `cf-connectors.sh` failing.

#### The Question:

How can I get the CF connector wizard to succeed? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the support matrix at https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/coldfusion9-support-matrix-4-ue.pdf

Ubuntu 14.04 is not supported with CF9

Comment: @AnitKumar Thanks for that link! It looks like Ubuntu is not on the list of supported Linux operating systems. Support for Ubuntu appears to start at CF10: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf10/coldfusion10-support-matrix.pdf

Comment: Ubuntu 9.04 is supported with ColdFusion 9. See Linux 32-bit

Comment: Better suited for Server Fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache 2.4.x is not supported by Coldfusion 9, see my answer here:
[Apache won't start with ColdFusion 10: mod_jk.conf procedure not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742328/apache-wont-start-with-coldfusion-10-mod-jk-conf-procedure-not-found/18756854#18756854)

I suggest you install Apache 2.2 and then you should be able to install the Connector.

Answer (score 1):

While Apache 2.4 is not supported by Adobe, it is possible to get it running but recompiling the mod_jrun module against the Apache 2.4 sources (after a small modification to the source code).

There are full instructions on my blog post, if you're still interested.

[mod_jrun on Apache 2.4 (Ubuntu 14.04 + ColdFusion 9)](http://research.g0blin.co.uk/mod_jrun-on-apache-2-4-ubuntu-14-04-coldfusion-9/)